# Perl Import Package in different Namespace

Tags: perl, import, namespaces

is it possible to import (`use`) a perl module within a different namespace?

Let's say I have a Module `A` (XS Module with no methods Exported `@EXPORT` is empty) and I have no way of changing the module.

This Module has a Method `A::open`

currently I can use that Module in my main program (package main) by calling `A::open` I would like to have that module inside my `package main` so that I can directly call `open`

I tried to manually push every key of `%A::` into `%main::` however that did not work as expected.

The only way that I know to achieve what I want is by using `package A;` inside my main program, effectively changing the package of my program from `main` to `A`.
Im not satisfied with this. I would really like to keep my program inside package main.

Is there any way to achieve this and still keep my program in package main?

*Offtopic: Yes I know usually you would not want to import everything into your namespace but this module is used by us extensively and we don't want to type A:: (well the actual module name is way longer which isn't making the situation better)in front of hundreds or thousands of calls*

Comment: What do you mean by "did not work as expected"? How did you implement it, what did you expect?

Comment: Haven't tested it, but you might be able to do something with [our](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/our.html) to get the behavior you want.

Comment: You say that `@EXPORT` is empty, but is the module using Exporter?

Comment: In case it's a useful alternative, you can use [Package::Alias](https://metacpan.org/pod/Package::Alias) to alias your module `A` to a shorter name, if the problem is just that its real name is too long to use repeatedly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one of those "impossible" situations, where the clear solution -- to rework that module -- is off limits.

But, you *can* alias that package's subs names, from its symbol table, to the same names in `main`. Worse than being rude, this comes with a glitch: it catches all names that that package itself imported in any way. However, since this package is a fixed quantity it stands to reason that you can establish that list (and even hard-code it).  It is just this one time, right?

**main**

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use OffLimits;

GET_SUBS: {
    # The list of names to be excluded
    my $re_exclude = qr/^(?:BEGIN|import)$/;  # ...
    my @subs = grep { !/$re_exclude/ } sort keys %OffLimits::;
    no strict 'refs';
    for my $sub_name (@subs) {
        *{ $sub_name } = \&{ 'OffLimits::' . $sub_name };
    }   
};
    
my $name = name('name() called from ' . __PACKAGE__);
my $id   = id('id() called from ' . __PACKAGE__);

say "name() returned: $name";
say "id()   returned: $id";
```

with `OffLimits.pm`

```
package OffLimits;    
use warnings;
use strict;

sub name { return "In " .  __PACKAGE__ . ": @_" }
sub id   { return "In " .  __PACKAGE__ . ": @_" }

1;
```

It prints

```
name() returned: In OffLimits: name() called from  main
id()   returned: In OffLimits: id() called from  main
```

You may need that code in a `BEGIN` block, depending on other details.

Another option is of course to hard-code the subs to be "exported" (in `@subs`). Given that the module seems to be immutable in practice   this option is reasonable and more reliable.

---

This can also be wrapped in a module, so that you have the normal, selective, importing.

**WrapOffLimits.pm**

```
package WrapOffLimits;
use warnings;
use strict;

use OffLimits;

use Exporter qw(import);

our @sub_names;
our @EXPORT_OK   = @sub_names;
our %EXPORT_TAGS = (all => \@sub_names);

BEGIN { 
    # Or supply a hard-coded list of all module's subs in @sub_names
    my $re_exclude = qr/^(?:BEGIN|import)$/;  # ...
    @sub_names = grep { !/$re_exclude/ } sort keys %OffLimits::;

    no strict 'refs';
    for my $sub_name (@sub_names) {
        *{ $sub_name } = \&{ 'OffLimits::' . $sub_name };
    }   
};
1;
```

and now in the caller you can import either only some subs

```
use WrapOffLimits qw(name);
```

or all

```
use WrapOffLimits qw(:all);
```

with otherwise the same main as above for a test.

The module name is hard-coded, which should be OK as this is meant only for that module.

---

The following is added mostly for completeness.

One can pass the module name to the wrapper by writing one's own `import` sub, which is what gets used then. The import list can be passed as well, at the expense of an awkward interface of the `use` statement.

It goes along the lines of

```
package WrapModule;
use warnings;
use strict;

use OffLimits;

use Exporter qw();  # will need our own import 

our ($mod_name, @sub_names);

our @EXPORT_OK   = @sub_names;
our %EXPORT_TAGS = (all => \@sub_names);

sub import {
    my $mod_name = splice @_, 1, 1;  # remove mod name from @_ for goto

    my $re_exclude = qr/^(?:BEGIN|import)$/;  # etc

    no strict 'refs';
    @sub_names = grep { !/$re_exclude/ } sort keys %{ $mod_name . '::'};    
    for my $sub_name (@sub_names) {    
        *{ $sub_name } = \&{ $mod_name . '::' . $sub_name };
    }   

    push @EXPORT_OK, @sub_names;

    goto &Exporter::import;
}
1;
```

what can be used as

```
use WrapModule qw(OffLimits name id);  # or (OffLimits :all)
```

or, with the list broken-up so to remind the user of the unusual interface

```
use WrapModule 'OffLimits', qw(name id);
```

When used with the main above this prints the same output.

The `use` statement ends up using the [import](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/import.html) sub defined in the module, which exports symbols by writing to the caller's symbol table. (If no `import` sub is written then the `Exporter`'s `import` method is nicely used, which is how this is normally done.)

This way we are able to unpack the arguments and have the module name supplied at `use` invocation. With the import list supplied as well now we have to `push` manually to `@EXPORT_OK` since this can't be in the `BEGIN` phase. In the end the sub is replaced by `Exporter::import` via the (good form of) [goto](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/goto.html), to complete the job.

Comment: There's another "glitch" as you put it here: the stash will contain global variables and other stashes in that namespace as keys as well. For example if the package `OffLimits::Foobar` exists somewhere. My method of doing this would be something like `use Package::Stash; my @subs = grep { !/$re_exclude/ } Package::Stash->new('OffLimits')->list_all_symbols('CODE');`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i managed to get it to work by mixing your approach with mine. I will add a short answer as well to show how/what I did

Comment: @Simerax  Added a way to put this in a wrapper module, so that one can then use it with a normal import list, `use Wrapper qw(...);`, and import just the desired subs.  Then I also added a way to pass the name of the module to wrap, as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can forcibly "import" a function into main using glob assignment to alias the subroutine (and you want to do it in BEGIN so it happens at compile time, before calls to that subroutine are parsed later in the file):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Other::Module;

BEGIN { *open = \&Other::Module::open }
```

However, another problem you might have here is that open is a builtin function, which may cause some [problems](https://perldoc.pl/perlsub#Overriding-Built-in-Functions). You can add `use subs 'open';` to indicate that you want to override the built-in function in this case, since you aren't using an actual import function to do so.

Comment: Thanks for that answer. Helped a lot!

Comment: LOVE YOU!! ❤️ Seriously, trying to get an answer this question led me to *so* many bulky modules when I'm using perl on a board with 32MiB of storage and 256MiB of ram.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I now came up with. Yes this is hacky and yes I also feel like I opened pandoras box with this. However at least a small dummy program ran perfectly fine.

I renamed the module in my code again. In my original post I used the example `A::open` actually this module does not contain any method/variable reserved by the perl core. This is why I blindly import everything here.

```
BEGIN {
    # using the caller to determine the parent. Usually this is main but maybe we want it somewhere else in some cases
    my ($parent_package) = caller;

    package A;

    foreach (keys(%A::)) {
        if (defined $$_) {
            eval '*'.$parent_package.'::'.$_.' = \$A::'.$_;
        }
        elsif (%$_) {
            eval '*'.$parent_package.'::'.$_.' = \%A::'.$_;
        }
        elsif (@$_) {
            eval '*'.$parent_package.'::'.$_.' = \@A::'.$_;
        }
        else {
            eval '*'.$parent_package.'::'.$_.' = \&A::'.$_;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: String eval is not needed here, you can simply `no strict 'refs';` in that scope and then construct the names, while it's still pretty crazy, it would be much less so. `*{"${parent_package}::$_"} = \${"A::$_"};`

Comment: One problem with this is that each stash entry can contain multiple variable types, and even more than the 4 you are handling here. This is why I usually rely on [Package::Stash](https://metacpan.org/pod/Package::Stash) for finding particular stash entry types.